# In react-native, can tabs have auto width (like flex:auto)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tabs in react-native are all of the equal width, regardless of tab text length. I would like each tab to have auto width, dependent of it's name text width. Sort of like flex=auto for each tab. Is this possible?
I would also love to be able to justify-content:space-between, so instead of this:

[image: oh no so bad]

I would like this:

[image: yes this is nice]

Is this possible?